# How to install sp_whoisactive procedure

Tags: sql-server

While installing sp_whoisactive (ver. v11_30) on my SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition, I'm getting the error:

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_WhoIsActive, Line 198 [Batch Start Line 11]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_WhoIsActive, Line 201 [Batch Start Line 11]
> Incorrect syntax near ','."

All the databases have compatibility level 140/150.

What should I check?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't reproduce with 11.30 or 11.32, and those line numbers make me think something else is happening with your script because sp_whoisactive doesn't even get out of comments until line 350 or so, and I can't spot anything in the procedure that would fail with that message even if you weren't on the version of SQL Server you think you are.

Comment: (As an aside, have you considered trying [v12.00](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/releases)?

Comment: thanks Aaron, I've tried v.12 (from Github), the same error. I know, the procedure is OK, but still: I've got 3 SQL Instances (an AVG) and I get the same error message on those 3 instances...it's strange...

Comment: I'm not sure what an AVG is but without happening to us and without having any way to verify exactly what you're running and where I don't know how anybody here is going to be able to help you troubleshoot. It seems either the script you're running has been mangled or your batch separator in SSMS has been changed from `GO` to something else or you're simply not running what you think you are or where. I would suggest trying from a different machine or a VM with a fresh SSMS install just to rule out things you may have done to yourself.

Comment: AVG= Availability Group, as I said: 3 identical SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition.

Comment: That is definitely not a common acronym for Availability Group, so I really suggest not trying to make it one. :-) However whether it's an Availability Group or not has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing some weird database-level trigger

Comment: the problem was the update of SQL Management Studio. I think the update to ver. 18.11 went wrong. I tested the sp_whoisactive with ver. 18.10 and there no problems. Good to know. Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue currently occurs when you have SSMS set up to use "Always Encrypted" on the connection.

When you reinstalled it it will have forgotten that setting allowing the creation to  succeed.

When this option is enabled it parses the batch into a syntax tree to identify changes it needs to make for the auto parameterisation.

The transformed text is just generated from the abstract syntax tree and has various changes - including not appending semi colons after the `END` keyword which [causes the problem in this case](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/321821/3690).